# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapterPosts has not been initialized

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
Process: com.example.socialapplication, PID: 31405
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapterPosts has not been initialized
        at com.example.socialapplication.Fragment.HomeFragment.access$getAdapterPosts$p(HomeFragment.kt:24)
        at com.example.socialapplication.Fragment.HomeFragment$loadPosts$postData$1.onDataChange(HomeFragment.kt:104)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

Source Code

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

    .....
    private lateinit var adapterPosts : AdapterGrid

    .....

    adapterPosts = AdapterGrid(activity, postList)
    adapterPosts.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    recyclerView.adapter = adapterPosts // getting error
```

REQUIRED CODE

```
    @Suppress("ControlFlowWithEmptyBody", "DEPRECATION")
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var firebaseAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var ref : DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mDatabase: FirebaseDatabase

    private lateinit var shimmerPost : ShimmerFrameLayout
    private lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var postList : ArrayList<ModelPost>
    private lateinit var adapterPosts : AdapterGrid


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        findView(view)
        initView(view)

        return view
    }

    override fun findView(view: View) {

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.postsRecyclerview)
        shimmerPost = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view)

    }

    override fun initView(view: View) {

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

        val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)

        // tampilkan posting terbaru terlebih dahulu, untuk memuat ini dari yang terakhir
//        layoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
//        layoutManager.reverseLayout = true
        //set layout untuk recyclerView
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        postList = arrayListOf()

        loadPosts()

    }

    override fun initListeners(view: View) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    private fun loadPosts() {

        val ref = mDatabase.getReference("Posts")

        val postData : ValueEventListener? = object : ValueEventListener{

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                postList.clear()
                for (ds : DataSnapshot in p0.children){

                    val modelPost = ds.getValue(ModelPost::class.java)

                    if (modelPost != null) {

                        postList.add(modelPost)
                    }
                    shimmerPost.stopShimmer()
                    shimmerPost.visibility = View.GONE
                    recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    //adapter
                    adapterPosts = AdapterGrid(activity, postList)
                    adapterPosts.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }
                //set adapter untuk recyclerView
                recyclerView.adapter = adapterPosts
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, p0.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        if (postData != null) {
            ref.addValueEventListener(postData)
        }else{
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are `.....` ? You probably have to add whole code because somehow `recyclerView.adapter = adapterPosts` being called before initialization.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem.  What you have now is not enough to tell what exactly went wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: kindly check above I shared required code, let me know If you need to see code of adater class

Comment: @Android i can't find where you used the `adapterPosts` in above posted code. Post homefragment code

Comment: The error says that you did not initialized `adapterPosts` before it gets used. And that access happens in `HomeFragment.kt:24`(Line 24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code .

1. You do not create `adapter` inside a loop .
2. You should not calling `notifyDataSetChanged` just after creating adapter its of no use it should only be called when there is a change in dataset actually.
3. The main reason for to your code to crash is `for-loop` never get executed because `DatasnapShot` is empty i guess.
   Correct the above mistakes .

   ```
   private fun loadPosts() {
    val ref = mDatabase.getReference("Posts")
    val postData: ValueEventListener? = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (isAdded()) {
                postList.clear()
                for (ds: DataSnapshot in p0.children) {
                    val modelPost = ds.getValue(ModelPost::class.java)
                    if (modelPost != null) {
                        postList.add(modelPost)
                    }
                }
                shimmerPost.stopShimmer()
                shimmerPost.visibility = View.GONE
                recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                // also check if postList is blank to show some error view for no data found
                adapterPosts = AdapterGrid(activity, postList)
                recyclerView.adapter = adapterPosts
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            if (isAdded())
                Toast.makeText(activity, p0.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    if (postData != null) {
        ref.addValueEventListener(postData)
    } else {
    }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when your loadPosts function called then it will start first `recyclerView.adapter = adapterPosts` this command. So just change the initialization location.

```
private fun loadPosts() {
    adapterPosts = AdapterGrid(activity, ArrayList());
    val ref = mDatabase.getReference("Posts")

    val postData : ValueEventListener? = object : ValueEventListener{

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            postList.clear()
            for (ds : DataSnapshot in p0.children){

                val modelPost = ds.getValue(ModelPost::class.java)

                if (modelPost != null) {

                    postList.add(modelPost)
                }
                shimmerPost.stopShimmer()
                shimmerPost.visibility = View.GONE
                recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                //adapter
                adapterPosts.arrayname.addAll(postList);
                adapterPosts.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
            //set adapter untuk recyclerView
            recyclerView.adapter = adapterPosts
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, p0.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    if (postData != null) {
        ref.addValueEventListener(postData)
    }else{
    }

}
```